# Spring 4 Migration: OutOfMemoryError: PermGen Space

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, out-of-memory, spring-4

While Migrating Spring 3.2 to Spring 4.1 I am getting the following error while hitting the JSP.

```
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:637)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:9910)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:9890)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.dietParse(Parser.java:8454)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.internalBeginToCompile(Compiler.java:718)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.beginToCompile(Compiler.java:383)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:428)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:450)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:356)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:334)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:321)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:592)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:328)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:436)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:374)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:302)
```

The rest services and other internal business logics of the application works fine. whenever I try to hit any jsp, i got the following error.

These are the JSP related dependencies I use in my app.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I use tile 3 and added all the related dependencies of Tiles. 
Any idea how to resolve this???? Also, help me out with the Dependencies, I have Spring MVC application with Apache Tiles and JSPs as the front-end.

Answer (score 0):

Your stack trace says that you've run out of PermGen space so you need to allocate some more.  There's a link here which guides you through the steps to do this for tomcat:
http://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/tomcat-javalangoutofmemoryerror-permgen-space/

Basically, you just need to add

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=<size>
```

to the JVM arguments used to start tomcat, where `<size>` is the amount of perm gen space to allocate.  e.g.

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

In case you're interested, this isn't a direct result of upgrading your dependencies, more like a side effect - the newer versions of the libraries require more Perm Gen space, so during the upgrade, your app has gone over the existing limit, and thus you need to add more.